# Мне нужно внести данные в базу данных из формы, в зависимости от других введённых данных sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Только начала изучать работу с запросами, мне нужно чтобы в ячейку базы данных (phpmyadmin) вводились данные в зависимости от данных в другой ячейке
Например:
Если первая ячейка таблицы пустая, то в другую вносится 'правда', а
Если в первой содержится какой либо текст, то в другую вносится 'ложь'
Собственно вопрос, как мне написать такой запрос в sql?) (наверное, через if else, но это не точно)
Буду благодарна за помощь :)

Вот код, который использовала, но видимо, я где то ошиблась и он не работает:

```
"IF($comment IS NOT NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO `one` (`comment`, `statuss`)
        VALUES('$comment','Правда');
    ELSE INSERT INTO `one` (`comment`, `statuss`)
        VALUES('$comment','Ложь');
    END IF"
```

Comment: *мне нужно чтобы в ячейку базы данных (phpmyadmin)* Во-первых, ячейки в Экселе, а в базах данных - значения полей записей в таблицах. Во-вторых, phpMyAdmin ни фига не база данных, а клиентское приложение для доступа к базам данных MySQL и его форков.

Comment: *Например: Если первая ячейка таблицы пустая, то в другую вносится 'правда', а Если в первой содержится какой либо текст, то в другую вносится 'ложь'* - а вот для этого умные люди придумали вычисляемые поля ([generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)). В них вообще ничего вносить не нужно (и даже вредно - ибо приведёт к ошибке), зато при получении из такого поля значений они рассчитываются в соответствии с указанным выражением и без дополнительных телодвижений со стороны. [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/4np-WXK6).